# Can I return the tag and routine name?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I am working on a code "maintenance" idea where I would like to populate a global when routines are accessed and by who.  I can pull the current routine name using $t(+0) or $ZNAME, but what about the current tag and/or line offset?  Is there a way so I can put a standard line in the routines I want to track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob, you can get these information from $STACK.

If you call your own tracking function, you get the calling stack info like this:

```
W $STACK($STACK(-1)-1,"PLACE")
```

> zExecute+2^%Studio.General.1 +1

Take a look at the Caché ObjectScript Reference for $STACK for detailed description and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Rob!
Maybe you just turn on Audit? It gathers logs for different users activities in InterSystems Caché database. See the [documentation on Caché Audit](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_audit).

Also, [see this solution](https://github.com/intersystems-ru/deepseeaudit) which will help you to examine analytics in DeepSee regarding Audit entries.

Comment: That might be an option.  I'll have to check with our DB guys.  They don't like to do thing that aren't in their standard workflow though, so I'm not very optomistic.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the routine that's calling your label, by the following ClassMethod.

```
write ##class(%SYSTEM.Process).CallingRoutine()
```

As well as the database which is calling your label.

```
write ##class(%SYSTEM.Process).CallingDatabase()
```

Comment: I could not get this to work.  Here is my code:<pre>
routest1 ;
 d routest^ZUUJUNK
 q
routest ;
    w "Routine: "_$$zCurrRou(),!
 w "Tag: "_$$zTagDefn(),!
 w "$ZNAME: "_$ZNAME,!
 w $t(+1),!
 w "Routine: "_##class(%SYSTEM.Process).CallingRoutine(),!
 w "Label: "_##class(%SYSTEM.Process).CallingDatabase(),!
 w "All together: "_$STACK($STACK(-1)-1,"PLACE"),!
 q
</pre>  The class calls returned the routine once, but now neither return anything.